# How can new objects be placed in an array as values?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Now I'm trying to add photos in my app.

For example, if there is one picture, the key is img_no_1, and the value is getting through the backend.

if can put up to 10 pictures, how can make img_no + number(The number of images.) according to the number of pictures?

I want to make a Array like imageList.

If there are five pictures,

```
const image_no = [145, 331, 392, 2, 39];
const imageList = [];


--------------------------------------------------------
imageList = [{
             img_no_1: 145,
             img_no_2: 331,
             img_no_3: 392,
             img_no_4: 2,
             img_no_5: 39
     }];
```

Thanks for your attention.

Comment: I would suggest using `map` and then `Object.fromEntries`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a very naive example using `map` and then `Object.fromEntries`:

1. use `map` to return an array of array values in the shape `["key", "value"]`
2. Convert this array of arrays into an object using `Object.fromEntries`

```js
const image_no = [145, 331, 392, 2, 39];
const imageList = [Object.fromEntries(
  image_no.map((num, i) => [
    `img_no_${i+1}`,
    num
  ])
)];

console.log(imageList)
```

If `image_no` is an array of image numbers:

```js
const image_nos = [
  [145, 331, 392, 2, 39],
  [145, 331, 392, 2, 39]
];
const imageList = image_nos.map(image_no => Object.fromEntries(
  image_no.map((num, i) => [
    `img_no_${i+1}`,
    num
  ])
));

console.log(imageList)
```

Comment: Cuz that array can be multiple as [{img_no_1: xx},{img_no_1: xx, img_no_2: xx}]

Comment: I've added an example for a multiple variant.

Comment: Nice. I was going to comment on a previous version of this answer to suggest using computed property names (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Object_initializer#computed_property_names), but I see my help is not needed here :)